# Viewing expired entries and live one with the same template

Tags: entries, status, expiration

Working with Craft 2, I have a channel for events that each entry has an expiration date. Live entries should show the upcoming event info and expired entries should show archive info.

I have created a costume route to enable viewing of the expired entries:

```
news/{slug} →  news/_entry
```

when I am adding this to the code:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').slug(slug).status('live, expired').first() %}
```

I can see the expired entries info but than if I am viewing a live entry, the data that I am viewing is not from the entry I am visiting but from the first entry in the section. If I drop this line from my code, than I cannot see the info from the expired entries.

Is there a way to be able to view both?

Comment: Is it for Craft 2 or Craft 3?

Comment: I am working with Craft 2